# Having trouble using a form button with Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to use a form button with spring MVC.  Once you click on the form button it will take you to another page (showData.jsp).  Unfortunately, when I click on the button nothing happens.  I'll provide my code below and thank you for any help.

**JSP file with form code:**

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showPage">

    <button type="button" value="button" name="button"> Click Here!</button>

</form:form>
```

**Controller code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String printWelcome() {

    return "showData";
}
```

**Dispatcher-servlet**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: show spring application.xml

Comment: I added my dispatcher-servlet.xml.  Is that what you were referring to?  I couldn't find a application.xml file.  My gut tells me that I need to add something in the dispatcher-servlet.xml file but not sure....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use input tag instead of button tag:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showPage">
     <input type="submit" value="Click here!" name="button" />
</form:form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

your button may look like this:

```
<form:button id="button" name="button" value="click" >Save</form:button>
```

and your mapping can have something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params="click")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).